# Foreach scope variable in laravel blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

ok I got this 'main' blade template with laravel Collection object called `$projects` and passed to the view

'main.blade.php'

```
...
<div id="projects-list">
    <?php $last_id = 0; ?>
    @include('partials._project')
</div>

<div>{{ $last_id }}</div>
...
```

and 'partials._project.blade.php' template looks like this

```
@foreach($projects as $project)

    <?php $last_id = $project->id ?>

    <a href="{{ action('ProjectController@index', $project->uri) }}">
        <h4>{{ $last_id }}</h4> 
        <img src="{{ $project->getProjectImage($project->poster) }}">
    </a>
@endforeach
```

The issue is that at this point `<h4>{{ $last_id }}</h4>` i get the correct value of project ID (so the last block shows value of `6`)

BUT in my main.blade.php at `<div>{{ $last_id }}</div>` (after the loop is over) I get `0` (the initial value)

I guess blade `@foreach` loop have no influance on outer scope's variables...
Or am I wrong?

Comment: how the `main.blade.php`  linked with `partials._project.blade.php` .You can access if you pass the `$last_id` from the controller!

Comment: is `partials._project.blade.php` a filename?

Answer (score -1):

if i understand correctly, in your loop, php creates local variable `$last_id`, it doesn't use your global variable `$last_id`. in your case, you run the loop, create local variable `$last_id` and put there value from `$project->id`. your global variable `$last_id` wasn't changed. after loop is finished, you output `$last_id` from global scope, which wasn't change, so it equals to 0, as you defined it

Comment: Ok, so how do I work around this?..
I need to assign a value to the outside variable inside the loop and then get acces to that value outside the loop. 
Or is that impossible in blade?

Comment: try to assign variable in `$GLOBALS` array. in your main.blade `<?php $GLOBALS['last_id'] = 0; ?> ` instead of `<?php $last_id = 0; ?>` in your loop `<?php $GLOBALS['last_id'] = $project->id ?>` and then `{{ $GLOBALS['last_id'] }}`